# How to prevent/keep tail from replacing \r by \n

Tags: linux, tail, nohup

When I play a video with mpv in the backgroud, I get this :

```bash
$ tail -f nohup.out 
Playing: https://www.facebook.com/TBN/videos/1580372468665943/
 (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (h264 1266x720 30.000fps)
 (+) Audio --aid=1 (*) 'DASH audio' (aac 1ch 48000Hz) (external)
File tags:
 Artist: TBN
 Date: 20180113
 Title: Joseph Prince joins Matt & Laurie TONIGHT on PRAISE... watch NOW!
AO: [pulse] 48000Hz mono 1ch float
VO: [gpu] 1266x720 yuv420p
AV: 00:00:00 / 00:56:50 (0%) A-V:  0.000
AV: 00:00:00 / 00:56:50 (0%) A-V:  0.000
AV: 00:00:00 / 00:56:50 (0%) A-V:  0.000
... # THERE ARE QUITE A LOT OF LINES
AV: 00:00:03 / 00:56:50 (0%) A-V:  0.000
AV: 00:00:03 / 00:56:50 (0%) A-V:  0.000
Saving state.


Exiting... (Quit)
^C
```

but I'd love to have this output instead (just like when I play the file without the `nohup`) :

```bash
$ mpv --no-resume-playback https://www.facebook.com/TBN/videos/1580372468665943/
Playing: https://www.facebook.com/TBN/videos/1580372468665943/
 (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (h264 1266x720 30.000fps)
 (+) Audio --aid=1 (*) 'DASH audio' (aac 1ch 48000Hz) (external)
File tags:
 Artist: TBN
 Date: 20180113
 Title: Joseph Prince joins Matt & Laurie TONIGHT on PRAISE... watch NOW!
AO: [pulse] 48000Hz mono 1ch float
VO: [gpu] 1266x720 yuv420p
AV: 00:00:03 / 00:56:50 (0%) A-V:  0.000
Saving state.


Exiting... (Quit)
```

EDIT1 : I use a tty like `/dev/pts/2`, therefore if I type `stty inlcr` it should impact the current tty.

I still get the same messy output in `tail -f nohup.out`

EDIT2 : According to @mosvy `tail` is not the one to blame but `mpv` is.

I've figured out a way to do a S&R on `mpv`'s `stderr` :

```bash
$ mpv --no-resume-playback https://www.facebook.com/TBN/videos/1580372468665943/ 2>&1 | perl -p -e '$| = 1;s/\n/\r/g if $_ =~ /^AV:/;s/Saving state/\nSaving state/' | tee mpv_all.log
Playing: https://www.facebook.com/TBN/videos/1580372468665943/
 (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (h264 634x360 30.000fps)
 (+) Audio --aid=1 (*) (aac 1ch 48000Hz)
AO: [pulse] 48000Hz mono 1ch float
VO: [gpu] 634x360 yuv420p
AV: 00:00:08 / 00:56:50 (0%) A-V:  0.000 Cache: 1024s+86MB
Saving state.
[ffmpeg] https: Will reconnect at 63421312 in 0 second(s), error=End of file.


Exiting... (Quit)
```

EDIT 3: @mosvy Thanks, it works now :

```bash
$ nohup sh -c ' mpv --no-resume-playback https://www.facebook.com/TBN/videos/1580372468665943/ 2>&1 | perl -p -e '\''$| = 1;s/\n/\r/g if $_ =~ /^AV:/;s/Saving state/\nSaving state/'\'' ' &
$ tail -f nohup.out
Playing: https://www.facebook.com/TBN/videos/1580372468665943/
 (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (h264 634x360 30.000fps)
 (+) Audio --aid=1 (*) (aac 1ch 48000Hz)
AO: [pulse] 48000Hz mono 1ch float
VO: [gpu] 634x360 yuv420p
AV: 00:00:08 / 00:56:50 (0%) A-V:  0.000 Cache: 1767s+147MB
Saving state.
[ffmpeg] https: Will reconnect at 103693952 in 0 second(s), error=End of file.


Exiting... (Quit)
^C
```

EDIT 4 : Another solution thanks to @jw013 :

```bash
export perl_script='$| = 1;s/\n/\r/g if $_ =~ /^AV:/;s/Saving state/\nSaving state/'
mpv="command mpv"
args=("$@")
nohup sh -c "$mpv ${args[*]} 2>&1 | perl -p -e '$perl_script' | tee ~/mpv_all.log" &
```

<s>How can I do this ?</s> SOLVED !

Comment: I don't think you can do this. When you write to a terminal, you can overwrite the previous line, but when you pipe the output somewhere, you can't "go back", it's up to the program o the receiving end of the pipe to decide what it does with the data. In this case the video player writes to nohup.out,, and `tail` mere reads what's there. You could write a program that you use instead of `tail` and then handle the changing lines yourself.

Comment: I think `stty` is what you are looking for, maybe `stty -F /dev/ttyS0 inlcr`.  Checkout this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812142/how-to-toggle-cr-lf-in-gnu-screen

Comment: @runwuf It does not seem to work on a virtual terminal (such as `/dev/pts/7`). Can you please give more details on how to make this to work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tail` is **not** replacing `\r` by `\n`.

It's your `mpv` program which is adjusting its status output depending on whether its stderr is a terminal.

Trivial test about `tail` not replacing the `\r` with `\n`:

```
$ nohup sh -c 'while printf "s=$((s=s+1))\r"; do sleep 1; done' &
[1] 3897
$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'

$ tail -f nohup.out
s=8  # s=9, s=10 ... on the same line
```

---

Just as its parent `mplayer`, `mpv` is quite ornery when someone tries to run it in a way different of how its authors imagined it; I wasn't able to find any option for making it print its status in the same way as on a terminal when its stderr is a regular file or pipe. The easiest thing you can do is to run it in a separate `screen`/`tmux` window, rather than with `nohup`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, `mpv` seems to be the guilty one. `mpv` seem to translate `\r` by `\n` when its `stderr` is redirected to a file or a pipe

Comment: I've figured out a wav but I'm having a hard time quoting my command to put it inside a `nohup sh -c`, can you please read my EDIT2 and help ?

Comment: You can replace each single quote `'` inside `'...'` with `'\''`, put the perl command in a variable then `perl -pe "$perl_script"`, etc.

Comment: Does not work : `perl_script='\''$| = 1;s/\n/\r/g if $_ =~ /^AV:/;s/Saving state/\nSaving state/'\''` is prompting PS2 prompt. What is wrong ?

Comment: either extra var or extra escapes, not both. `nohup sh -c 'mpv ... 2>&1 | perl -pe '\''$|=1; s/\n/\r/ if /%\)$/'\' &`.

Comment: I also tried putting the perl script in the `perl_script` variable but I have a problem with quoting :  
`export mpv_Output_Perl_Script="'\$| = 1;s/\n/\r/g if \$_ =~ /^AV:/;s/Saving state/\nSaving state/'" `  
and here is my `sh -c` command :
`sh -c "$mpv $@ | perl -p -e \"$mpv_Output_Perl_Script\""`
What is going on ?

Comment: `script='$|=1; s/\n/\r/ if /%\)$/' nohup sh -c 'mpv ... 2>&1 | perl -pe "$script"' &`

Comment: Can you please give your `script` variable complete value ? It appears something is wrong with it :
`export script='$|=1; s/\n/\r/ if /%\)$/';nohup sh -c 'mpv ... 2>&1 | perl -pe "$script"' &`

Comment: I've tested that command, the `script` var is the complete script. No need of `export`; `foo=bar command` will run `command` with `foo` in its environment, without also setting it for subsequent commands.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92160/discussion-between-sebma-and-mosvy).

Comment: I don't do chat, sorry ;-) But feel free to ask another question(s) about quoting, envvars, shell syntax, etc. In your case, you probably can get rid of `nohup` rather than struggling to pass commands to it: `(trap '' HUP; mpv ... 2>&1 | perl -pe '$|=1; s/\n/\r/ if /%\)$/'>logfile) &`

Comment: I use export because my script gets initialized of the beginning of a new script.

Comment: I have a `mpv` variable containing `command mpv` to prevent from calling my bash `mpv` function, so I wanted to call the `sh -c`, like this :
`script='$| = 1;s/\n/\r/g if $_ =~ /^AV:/;s/Saving state/\nSaving state/' nohup sh -c "$mpv $* | perl -pe \"$script\""`
But it does not work, quoting is such a pain in the .... (.... stands for neck, right :-D ) ! I'm going to post another question for that. Thanks for your precious help :-)